# File or directory not found - FLUKA software installation

Tags: virtualbox, files, directory, error-handling

I am trying to install the FLUKA software from the binaries. The file for FLUKA and all its libraries were downloaded from the cern website in a `.deb` format. That provided me with a `.deb` file in the downloads folder that I then extracted to a folder I made named `fluka`, and that folder contains 3 files as evident by this output of `ls -la ~/fluka`:

```
total 20 
drwxrwxr-x 4  moiz moiz 4096  4 april 11:03 . 
drwxrwxrw- 17 moiz moiz 4096  4 april 11:03 .. 
drwxr-xr-x 2  moiz moiz 4096 30 march 20:15 control 
drwxr-xr-x 4  moiz moiz 4096 30 march 20:15 data 
-rw-r--r-- 1  moiz moiz 4    30 march 20:15 debian-binary
```

There isn't an installation file rather it was a binary package that needs to be executed to get the software.

When I try to generate the executables using the command `dpkg -i ./fluka_4-3.2.x86-Linux-gfor9_amd64.deb`, I get an error:

```
root@moiz-VirtualBox:~# dpkg -i ./fluka_4-3.2.x86-Linux-gfor9_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/root/fluka/fluka_4-3.2.x86-Linux-gfor9_amd64.deb': No such file or directory
```

The binary is in 64 and required fortran which I have downloaded. However it still says file of directory not found.

I am new to Linux, so if there are any rookie beginner mistakes like not opening the terminal correctly or anything else please tell those too because its very likely its gonna end up being a dumb mistakes.

PS. I also have superuser privilages so its not that either. Given using the command `sudo -i` and I am running Ubuntu in virtual box machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not unpack the `.deb` file. Just download the file to any location. Let's say you're in the directory `/home/moiz`.

```
wget https://flukafiles.web.cern.ch/flukafiles/fluka-4-3.2/fluka_4-3.2.x86-Linux-gfor9_amd64.deb
```

Now, run the `dpkg` command properly:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./fluka_4-3.2.x86-Linux-gfor9_amd64.deb
```

And the package manager will install the application for you.

Comment: it seems like the not debian format error was due to an incorrect download I will download it again and try once more

Comment: Do try one more time - and maybe afterwards, you could clean up your question, leaving out unneeded parts. That would be a nice thing to do!  The core issue seemed to be that you unpacked the `.deb` archive while you shouldn't have done so.

Comment: Well, if you focus the question down to the core, I'll remove my downvote, and I'm pretty sure others will as well..